# Magento 1.9.3.6 Connect not showing available Community Extension Upgrades

Tags: magento, centos, upgrade

My Magento install is not showing any available upgrades for Community Extensions.

When I run mage from the command line I receive No updates available (Magento is up to date). It does show the installed modules so no problem with the packages.xml.

To test I restored an older version and re-ran the upgrade, this shows me all of the current Magento core upgrades. However nothing for the extensions (which mirrors what I see with the live install)

If I log into Magento Connect it shows all my installed extensions and their versions but nothing in the column that shows the available version.

n98-magerun :sys:check shows no problems

I have googled and tried everything I can think of and can't figure it out

We are running CentOS 7.4

Any pointers would be very helpful :)

Thanks
Darren